# Basic image upload does not work: "405 Method not allowed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, upload, sapui5

I try to upload an image to my Express server using [FileUploader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.64.1/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader), but it does not work.

I've already tried to change some parameters (sendXHR="true") or used a [tutorial](http://www.techippo.com/2017/03/upload-images-to-server-sapui5-hybrid-app.html) but none of these options work for me.

My View:

```
        <u:FileUploader
            id="fileUploader"
            name="myFileUpload"
            uploadUrl="upload/"
            tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
            sendXHR="true" 
            uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete"/>
        <Button
            text="Upload File"
            press="handleUploadPress"/>
```

My Controller:

```
handleUploadComplete: function (oEvent) {
    var sResponse = oEvent.getParameter("response");
    if (sResponse) {
        var sMsg = oEvent.getParameter("status");                           console.log(oEvent.getParameter("status"));

                    MessageToast.show(sMsg);
                }
            },

            handleUploadPress: function (oEvent) {
                var oFileUploader = this.byId("fileUploader");
                oFileUploader.upload();
            }
```

Comment: Your server returns HTTP 405, thus it is wise to check this first. I'm using FileUploader in many scenarios and it works as expected.

Comment: @matbtt, the sapui5 server i am using is the SAP Neo Cloud with no configuration changes. I do not think this could be the Problem. It still doesnt work at the sample in the API Reference from SAPUI5